# Highlight a single data point on a graph with ~1800 (R)

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset

I know that the row of data I want is row 1535.

```
plot(data.exoplanets$loga, data.exoplanets$logMass, ylab="Log of Mass", xlab="Log of Semi Major Axis")
```

is the code I used to plot the initial graph, where I have assigned loga and logMass to two different collumns in the data.

I need to highlight just one and add error bars to it.

Answer (score 4):

Something like...

```
points(data.exoplanets$loga[1535], data.exoplanets$logMass[1535], col="red")
```

will replot your specific point with the color of choice. You could add vertical error bars using...

```
lines(rep(data.exoplanets$loga[1535],2), c(lower.error, upper.error), col="red")
```

What this does is repeat the x-value so you're plotting a vertical line. You'd need to specify the upper and lower error values you want to plot.

Try the following, and see what it's doing. Notice the `pch` and `type` arguments that I'm using. I'm adding errors bars that extend 5% above and below the value of the point I'm highlighting.

```
x<-0:100                       #creating a vector of x-values
y<-rnorm(length(x), 10, 1)     #creating a vector of y-values

plot(x, y)  #plotting
points(x[10], y[10], col="red", pch=16) #highlighting the tenth point

#and adding error bars around the tenth point
lines(rep(x[10],2), c(y[10]*.95, y[10]*1.05), col="red", type="o", pch="_")
```

Comment: Many thanks, the first line works great!
The second, to plot error bars, has no effect on the graph?
I've tried making the errors large so that they will definitely be seen but that still yields no lines.

Comment: That works great for the data set you've supplied. I tried using your lines code word for word replacing each value as needed.
`lines(rep(data.exoplanets$loga[1535],2), c(y[0.0037],y[0.0037]), col="red", type="o", pch="_")`

but I get the error "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ"

Comment: @JeremyMiles check my previous comment :)

Comment: `c(y[0.0037],y[0.0037])` is not appropriate. This is requesting the 0.0037th point in the vector `y`, neither of which exist in your original code, which is why you are getting the error. You simply need to define where you want your error bars to start and stop. `c(-10,10) #will plot a vertical bar from -10 to 10` `#the following will plot a vertical bar 5% above and below the value of your 1535th point` `c(data.exoplanets$logMass[1535]*.95, data.exoplanets$logMass[1535]*1.05)`

Comment: Oh I see, that make a lot more sense. Thank you.
So is it not possible to plot a vertical bar, 0.0037 above and below my point?

**Ignore that, I can just add and subtract it onto my value!
Thanks for all your help**

Comment: It is possible... Just plot your point with the error value added and subtracted from the point `c(data.exoplanets$logMass[1535]-0.0037, data.exoplanets$logMass[1535]+0.0037)`

Comment: @Jack, please help me how to put the minimum point coordinates in the graph among multiple lines graph? For example, if the minimum coordinates in the graph (17, 75.12), how to locate in the graph itself? I only want the minimum point coordinates?